# Is it possible to set the default initial startup size of an Eclipse RCP application?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm working on creating an application using Eclipse Rich Client Platform, and I'm currently looking for a method to establish the default initial window size for when the application first launches. My project is based on Eclipse version 4.31, and I've noticed that the starting window size has traditionally been 1000 x 760 pixels across various versions of Eclipse. I'm interested in setting the initial size to 1280 x 720 pixels or another dimension that maintains a 16:9 aspect ratio.

Additionally, it's important that if a user manually adjusts the window size, the application should remember and use the user's customized settings instead of reverting to the default dimensions upon restarting.

Comment: For an e4 RCP it is set in the main Trimmed Window in the Application.e4xmi or you can set it in the LifeCycle class. As long as the workbench is persisted any changes the user makes will be saved in the persisted e4xmi. I'm not sure about a 3.x compatability RCP.

Comment: @greg-449, I basically copy and pasta'ed the contents of `org.eclipse.platform/LegacyIDE.e4xmi` into my own Application.e4xmi, and referenced it with `value="my.plugin/Application.e4xmi">` as well as changed this part, `width="2000" height="2000"`. But that didn't seem to make a difference

Comment: As I said I don't know what works for a 3.x compatabilty RCP.